# Replace facebook dialog with custom dialog in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to run example of facebook android sdk , in that i have run stream example to fetch the 
data from facebook.

Now hen ever i click on "fconnect" button to log in into facebook i am getting following dialog box
[image]

so is it possible to replace this dialog box with following to make it simple ???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

look in the facebook source what the login dialog does when you press the login-button,
but if the dialog is a webview it could be more difficult. :/

Comment: well i think they have used WebView as i found 

private class FbWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 

so it there any way to get rid of it , because in my application i am accessing Facebook , picasa and flickr and to give a consistent look i need to replace the dialog